# Is the Sun slightly blue in the center? - Wavelength-dependent limb darkening of the Sun

Tags: stellar-astrophysics, the-sun, photography

I've slightly modified the title to try to attract some attention. If we call sunlight "white" and limb darkening is a result of seeing deeper at normal incidence and shallower at oblique incidence, then *the center end edge of the solar disk viewed from earth should appear to have slightly different effective color temperatures, since the temperature is varying rapidly with depth*.

I'd like to have an approximate expression for the wavelength-dependent limb darkening of the sun in the visible spectrum, either a relatively simple analytical expression that I can understand (with the appropriate coefficients for the sun) or just some linear images of the sun in various bands in the visible wavelengths so I can try to make one of my own.

This [question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/12331/7982) received this helpful [comment](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/12331/linear-limb-darkening-coefficient-u#comment17382_12331) which links [to here](http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/jkt/codes/jktld.html) but honestly I can't make my way through that to a practical expression I can use. The [Wikipedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMyje.jpg) article is not helping me much either, except for the [image there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:2012_Transit_of_Venus_from_SF.jpg). I plotted scans of RGB but by the time an image gets into the internet, things like sRGB and gamma mean it may not be linear.

**update:** At the [Solar Dynamics Observatory (SDO)](http://sdo.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/) website, I just found the image [sdo.gsfc.nasa.gov/assets/img/latest/latest_1024_HMIIC.jpg](http://sdo.gsfc.nasa.gov/assets/img/latest/latest_1024_HMIIC.jpg). The color gradient of the limb darkening seems very similar to the Wikimedia image below. I've discovered that it is called a "colorized intensitygram" and the color gradient is purely artificial - the data is single channel intensity. The limb darkening is certainly real (compare to the artificially "flattented" display!)

From http://www.solarham.net/latest_imagery/hmi1.htm

[image]

I appreciate (the existence of) the complexities and intricacies of photon transport, instrumental effects, and color perception, but I am *just starting* to do astronomically correct animations, so please for right now, something imperfect, or not absolutely correct is good enough for me.

*20 pixel wide averages of horizontal (-) and vertical (--) "scans" across the center of this 600x600 pixel [image from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:2012_Transit_of_Venus_from_SF.jpg)*

**note:** It seems this is a somewhat futile example, as the image is likely to be a monochrome continuum image with false color!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find this paper helpful:

http://www.physics.hmc.edu/faculty/esin/a101/limbdarkening.pdf

Look specifically at Eq. 5 for the wavelength dependence.  To get the intensity, use Equation 1.  The value of $u$ can be found in the caption to Figure 2.

Comment: Thanks. In section 2 1st paragraph: "Putting $u$ = 1 in Eq. 1, a single-parameter power law fit is performed..."  and since [Petro et al. (1984)](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1984ApJ...283..426P&defaultprint=YES&filetype=.pdf) is only narrow-band continuum at 4451Å Its not clear to me yet if the paper really says $u=0.85$ is a good fit throughout the visible wavelength range. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: also found **PS** ([Pierce and Slaughter 1977](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1977SoPh...51...25P&defaultprint=YES&filetype=.pdf)) and **NL** ([Neckel and Labs 1994](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1994SoPh..153...91N&defaultprint=YES&filetype=.pdf)).